# How do i add a book to my collection if it is not already in it? (java)

Tags: java, loops

I created a BookCollection class, that holds Books (another class I made). I am trying to merge two BookCollections together, to make collection3. If they have duplicate books I add their stock and take the lowest price. If they are not a duplicate I add the book to collection3. I understand how to get duplicate books handled, but my loop does not work for unique books. here is my code, I think you can understand my goal without seeing all the other code involved:

```
 public static BookCollection merge(BookCollection collection1, 
                                  BookCollection collection2){
   //Make sure the collection is big enough
  int collection1Size = collection1.getSize();
  int collection2Size = collection2.getSize();
  int collection3Size = collection1Size + collection2Size;
  BookCollection collection3 = new BookCollection(collection3Size);

  //loop through collection one and add it to collection 3
  for (int i = 0; i < collection1Size; i++){
     Book collection1Book = new Book(collection1.objectAt(i));
     collection3.addBook(collection1Book);
  }

  //loop through collection two and add certain books to collection 3

  for (int q = 0; q < collection3Size; q++){
     if (collection3.objectAt(q) != null){
       Book collection3Book = new Book(collection3.objectAt(q));
      for (int j = 0; j < collection2Size; j++){
         if (collection2.objectAt(j) != null){
          Book collection2Book = new Book(collection2.objectAt(j));

        // if the book at collection 2 is the same as a book already in collection 3
           if (collection2Book.getIsbn().equals(collection3Book.getIsbn())){
               String BookISBN = collection2Book.getIsbn();

               //Handles the price of the book
               double price1 = collection2Book.getPrice();
               double price2 = collection3Book.getPrice();
               if (price1 > price2){
                 collection3.changePrice(BookISBN, price2);
                }
               if (price1 < price2){
                 collection3.changePrice(BookISBN, price1);
               } 
               // Handles the stock of the book
               int stock1 = collection2Book.getStock();
               collection3.changeStock(BookISBN, stock1);                  
           }

           // adds the rest of the new books from collection 2 to collection
           if (!(collection2Book.getIsbn().equals(collection3Book.getIsbn()))){
              if (collection3.getSize() < collection3Size){
                 collection3.addBook(collection2Book);
              }

           }
         }
       } 
      }
    }   
  return collection3;
}
```

First I add all the books from collection1 to collection3. Then i create loops to check for duplicate books in collection2 and collection3.
Pseudocode is fine, I just don't know how to get my program to see that a book from collection2 is unique. Thank you!

Comment: It would be a bit easier to understand if you used normal `Collection` methods like `get` and `add`.  We have no way of knowing what is happening in `addBook` and `objectAt`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the approach your code is taking:

```
for each B3 in collection 3
    for each B2 in collection 2
        if B2 and B3 are the same book, then make some changes to the book
        if B2 and B3 are not the same book, then add it
    end
end
```

This doesn't do what you want.  In order to tell whether a book in collection 2 is unique, you must *first* compare the book to **all** the existing books.  Only after you have gone through all the books in collection 3, will you know whether you should add it as a new book.  Your code doesn't do that--because the "not the same book" logic is occurring way too early.

A correct approach would be something like

```
for each B2 in collection 2
    for each B3 in collection 3
        if B2 and B3 are the same book, then make some changes to the book--and make a note that B2 has been found
    end
    if B2 has not been found then add it
end
```

Note that the last check must be outside the inner loop.

Comment: Ok i see what you are saying, how would you go about marking something like this in a loop? each time it loops through it will change

Comment: Use a `boolean` variable.  Declare the variable outside the inner loop.  Initialize it to `false`, then set it to `true` when appropriate.  Don't ever change it back to `false` inside the inner loop.  I'm being very general about this to try to get you to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of code snippet...

```
public class BookCollection {

    class Book {
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object that) {
            // Determine criteria for equality e.g: Comparing only unique id or price
            return this.equals(that);
        }
    }

    private List<Book> collection = new ArrayList<BookCollection.Book>();;

    public List<Book> getCollection() {
        return collection;
    }

    public void setCollection(List<Book> collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
    }

    public BookCollection merge(BookCollection b1, BookCollection b2) {
        BookCollection b3 = new BookCollection();
        b3.getCollection().addAll(b1.getCollection());
        for (Book book : b2.getCollection()) {
            if (!b3.getCollection().contains(book))
                b3.getCollection().add(book);
        }
        return b3;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: No, it does not help--not if he's trying to learn.  Basically, you just threw out all his code and told him to use yours.  That is not the way to help him learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added collection3.addBook(collection2Book); in the second condition where there is duplicate entries are copied from the bookcollection2.

```
      if (collection2Book.getIsbn().equals(collection3Book.getIsbn())) {
           String BookISBN = collection2Book.getIsbn();
           collection3.addBook(collection2Book);
           //Handles the price of the book
           double price1 = collection2Book.getPrice();
           double price2 = collection3Book.getPrice();
           if (price1 > price2){
             collection3.changePrice(BookISBN, price2);
            }
           if (price1 < price2){
             collection3.changePrice(BookISBN, price1);
           } 
           // Handles the stock of the book
           int stock1 = collection2Book.getStock();
           collection3.changeStock(BookISBN, stock1);                  
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

1. Scrap your `BookCollection` - the JDK already has one of those: `Collection<Book>`
2. Make `Book` implement `Comparable<Book>`, so Books can be sorted
3. Add all books from both lists into a new List (using `addAll()`)
4. Call `Collections.sort(myNewList);` to sort them
5. iterate over the books using an iterator keeping a reference to the previous book (initialized to the first book if it's null). If the current book is "the same" as the previous book, merge it into the previous and call `iterator.remove()`

Comment: While this is certainly a better way to do it, I think it's still better in this case to focus on fixing the code he's written, rather than suggesting he scrap it and do it a simpler way.  What he's trying to do is a common idiom--where you go through a loop, but have to keep track of whether you've found something and then check _after_ the loop.  And it's an idiom that a lot of newer programmers get wrong.  I think it's important that he learn how to do the idiom right.